# Setting CustomDimensions with the Microsoft Extension Logging framework

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights, microsoft-extensions-logging

I have set up application insights for asp.net core project.

appsettings.json:

```
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": "90f786b7-36a5-xxxx-b1fc-xxxxxxxxx"
  },
```

Startup.cs:

```
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
```

And in my controller I can now log:

```
Logger.LogDebug("LogDebug");
```

I cant find any information on how to set CustomDemensions. I can see on the overloads there is an object array but not sure if that if for customdimensions. Any pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated:

```
            var dict = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "user_name","ivan"},{ "mycity","new york"} };

            using (_logger.BeginScope(dict))
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("this is a test message for testing purpose 456");
            }
```

---

**Original answer:**

For example, if you want to add the 2 properties city / user in customDimentions, please use the code below in the controller:

```
string city = "london";
string user = "jack";
_logger.LogInformation("{user} sends a  message from {city}", user, city);
```

Then in azure portal -> application insights logs:

[image]

Comment: WOW thanks. But that is really strange:D What if you don't want the parameters in your text?

Comment: I tried following but then it does not add the dimensions: Logger.LogDebug("LogDebug", lol1, lol2);

Comment: @ThomasSegato, let me try if it can work if without parameters in the text:).

Comment: Thanks Ivan appreciated.

Comment: @ThomasSegato, another way is to use BeginScope method, see the updated section.

Comment: Worked - highly appreciated. Thanks!